# How to use substr in Oracle ?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

there is a table column message value is

```
Command triggerEvent started
Command stopService stopped
Command startService started
Command executeCommand running
......
```

Now I want to select the command name, i.e. triggerEvent, stopService, startService

I try to use oracle substr and instr to get them but failed...

```
select substr(message, instr(message, ' ')) from event
```

Is there any good way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with shorter code using **REGEXP_SUBSTR**.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT 'Command triggerEvent started' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'Command stopService stopped' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'Command startService started' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'Command executeCommand running' str FROM dual
  6  )
  7  -- end of sample_data mocking as real table
  8  SELECT trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^ ]+', 1, 2)) command
  9  FROM sample_data;

COMMAND
------------------------------
triggerEvent
stopService
startService
executeCommand
```

Of course, better to use **SUBSTR** and **INSTR** as they are less **CPU intensive** as still **faster** than REGEX.

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT 'Command triggerEvent started' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'Command stopService stopped' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'Command startService started' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'Command executeCommand running' str FROM dual
  6  )
  7  -- end of sample_data mocking as real table
  8  SELECT trim(SUBSTR(str, instr(str, ' ', 1, 1),
  9                     instr(str, ' ', 1, 2) - instr(str, ' ', 1, 1))
 10              ) command
 11  FROM sample_data;

COMMAND
------------------------------
triggerEvent
stopService
startService
executeCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the second word from your message

```
with event(message) as (
select 'command triggerEvent started' from dual union
select 'Command stopService stopped' from dual) --recreate table

--query start
select trim(regexp_substr(message,'[[:alpha:]]+ ',1,2)) command FROM event
```

Comment: The problem with your regex is that it depends on the [[:alpha:]] character class, what if the command has characters other than alphabets. it would result NULL. Instead of depending on the string, better use the delimiter.

Comment: You are right. But the example OP gave didn't have non alphanumeric characters. But yeah better to be safe. :) Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Make sure u see the distinction between lobs and strings for substr !

```
select 
   substr(test, 4),
   dbms_lob.substr(test, 4)
from (
   select ('1234567890') test from dual
);
```

results in

[image]